# Oracle Installer:[INS-13001] Environment does not meet minimum requirements

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to install Oracle 11G R2 in windows 64-bit. But getting the below error

```
    Oracle Installer:[INS-13001] Environment does not meet minimum requirements
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After downloading the two zip files related to Oracle 11G R2.
Create a folder in some directory (For say "Oracle_11G_R2").
Extract both zip files into the same folder "Oracle_11G_R2".
And run setup.exe file present inside /database/setup.exe.
It should run correctly now.

Comment: What 2 zip files? There is only one zip file - without any "database" folder

Comment: @GilEpshtain they mean  Oracle-Client:
• Version 11.2.0
• https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win64soft-094461.html
• https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win32soft-098987.html

there ist two parts

Answer (score 16):

To prevent this dialog box from appearing, do the following:

1. Right click on the setup.exe for the Oracle 11g 32-bit client, and
   select Properties.
2. Select the Compatibility tab, and set the Compatibility mode to
   Windows 7. Click OK to close the Properties tab.
3. Double click setup.exe to install the client.

Answer (score 8):

It could be related with your Java version. Go ahead and download the Database version which includes Java.

However, if you are configuring a local development workstation I recommend you to download the Express Edition.

Here is the link:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/downloads/index-083047.html

or google this: OracleXE112_Win64

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

None of the other answers worked for me.

Make sure both unzipped files are in same folder, but also right click on setup.exe, select properties, compatibility, and then put a checkmark in "Run this program in compatibility mode for..." and select Windows 7.

I successfully launched the installer without the error message on Windows 10 for the 32-bit version of Oracle 11g release 2.

From:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21960606

Answer (score 1):

```
 $ yum -y install comapt-libstdc* libstdc++ libstdc++-devel libbaio-devel glib-devel glibc-headers glib-common kernel-header

$ yum -y install compat-libcap1 gcc gcc-c++ ksh compat-libstdc++-33 libaio-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

its awful oracle installer:

[INS-13001]

I got it as I used MY_PC as NETBIOS name instead of MYPC (Underscore is bad for it..)

Can be an historical reason.. but message is obscure.

Answer (score 1):

i was also getting this error, remove oracle folder from

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Inventory

and

> C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory

Also remove all component of oracle other version (which you had already in your system).

Go to services and remove all oracle component and delete old client from

> C:\app\username\product\11.2.0\client_1\

Answer (score 1):

To make [@Raghavendra's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2462838/raghavendra) answer more specific:

Once you've downloaded 2 zip files,

copy ALL the contents of "*win64_11gR2_database_2of2.zip -> Database -> Stage -> Components"* folder to 
"*win64_11gR2_database_1of2.zip -> Database -> Stage -> Components*" folder.

You'll still get the same warning, however, the installation will run completely without generating any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be connected as an administrator or execute the .exe file as an administrator